# using asp.net portal

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for ASP.NET applications that I can deploy to my local server. Can anyone suggest a link for open source .NET applications or any book?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of open source application you want?? are you learning .net?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 08 or 10 then they have built in ASP.NET Application Templates which will get you started.

These include a basic website with a Home and About page, also a Login/Register page and all the code to handle the Login and Registration.

If you create one of these, then you can deploy it to a local server as long as you have the .net framework, IIS and various other bits installed.

EDITS

Go and download the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). From here you can download various templates and up-to-date tools. I would upgrade from VS 05 to a newer version, maybe Visual Web Developer Express 2010 as this will give you more options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Visual studio 5. Can you give a link where I can find stand alone ASP.NET applications that can be deployed? Thanks